# Invalid byte sequence importing CSV created with R to Postgres

Tags: r, postgresql, utf-8

I would like to import a large R `data.frame` object into Postgres. I am saving the object as a CSV file using these commands:

```
> out_file <- paste(input_path, "data.csv", sep="")
> con<-file(out_file, encoding="UTF-8")
> write.csv(df, out_file)
```

No error messages are shown. Then switching to psql I issue the import with `COPY`, which results in this error:

```
# COPY data_in FROM 'data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xf8
CONTEXT:  COPY data_in, line 74358
```

Which software is failing here? Or is more guidance needed to get the correct encoding?

Comment: Try `write.csv(df, out_file,fileEncoding=TRUE)` or `write.csv(df, con)`. You are using the file path despite creating a connection object

Comment: @Rohit well spotted. Would you like to file that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment:

```
write.csv(df, out_file,fileEncoding=TRUE)
# write.csv(df, con)
```

Either of the above will work. If the encoding option is added to the connection, I don't think it doesn't affect the file itself.